# How to convince SOAP::Lite to return UTF-8 data in responses as UTF-8?

Tags: perl, soap, utf-8

I'm trying to transmit UTF-8 strings in complex data structures with SOAP::Lite. However, as it turns out, [SOAP::Lite quietly converts all UTF-8 strings into base-64-encoded octets](https://metacpan.org/source/MKUTTER/SOAP-Lite-0.714/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm#L271). The problem with that is that the deserializing [does not revert the conversion](https://metacpan.org/source/MKUTTER/SOAP-Lite-0.714/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.pm#L12) and only does [a straight base64 decode](https://metacpan.org/source/MKUTTER/SOAP-Lite-0.714/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_2.pm#L7).

This leaves me confused as to how a user is supposed to ensure that they get UTF-8 data from the SOAP::Lite response. Walking the tree and running `decode_utf8` on all strings seems wasteful.

Any suggestions?

Edit: In a nutshell, how do i make [this test](https://gist.github.com/1870757) pass without monkey-patching?

Comment: Have you considered XML::Compile? It's a complex piece of code, but the author is meticulous for correct support. From the people I know who've used it, it works much better for this stuff once you figure it out. I don't have experience with it myself.

Comment: Last time i looked at it i couldn't understand how to use it in the first place. I think i lack the required domain knowledge (in writing XSD and whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `is_utf8` (line 278) is evil and wrong. As we can't trust SOAP::Lite with encoding character data properly (to be fair, this code was likely written before word got around in the community how to do this particular kind of string processing), we shall give it octet data only and therefore have to handle encoding/decoding ourself. Pick a single encoding, apply it before handing off data to S::L, reverse it after receiving data.

```
use utf8;
use strictures;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use SOAP::Lite qw();
use Test::More;

my $original = 'mü';
my $xml      = SOAP::Serializer->envelope(
    freeform => encode('UTF-8', $original, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC)
);
my ($roundtrip) = map {
    decode('UTF-8', $_, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC)
} values %{SOAP::Deserializer->deserialize($xml)->body};

is(length($original), length($roundtrip),
    'Perl character string round-trips without changing length');
done_testing;
```

Comment: Please note how i said "complex datastructure". The test is minimal in order to keep the understanding effort low, but please imagine it's a four-dimensional hash that dumpers to 20kbyte or so. :)

Comment: I can float it. I can't entirely control the SOAP server, but i think he'll be open to suggestions. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: SOAP really is done best by encoding to JSON and sending that over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

I just hit the same problem and found the above discussion useful. As you say in the OP, the problem is that the data is encoded in base64 and the is_utf8  flag get lost. what happens in the serlializer treats any string with a non-ascii character as binary.  I got it to do what I wanted by tweaking the serializer as below. It could have odd consequences, but it works in my situation..

```
use strictures;
use Test::More;
use SOAP::Lite;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;
  
my $data = "mü\x{2013}";
my $ser = SOAP::Serializer->new;
$ser->typelookup->{trick_into_ignoring} = [9, \&utf8::is_utf8 ,'as_utf8_string'];
my $xml = $ser->envelope( freeform => $data ); 
my ( $cycled ) = values %{ SOAP::Deserializer->deserialize( $xml )->body };

is( length( $data ), length( $cycled ), "UTF-8 string is the same after serializing" );
done_testing;

sub check_utf8 {
    my ($val) = @_;
    return utf8::is_utf8($val);
}


package SOAP::Serializer;
sub as_utf8_string {
    my $self = shift;
    my($value, $name, $type, $attr) = @_;
    return $self->as_string($value, $name, $type, $attr);
}
1;
```

The 9 means the utf8 check is performed before the check for non-ascii characters. if the utf8 flag is on then it treats it as a 'normal' string.